# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Xamarin.Forms using Acr.XamForms.UserDialog

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, dialog, loading

In my app I fetch the data from the internet. While the data are being fetched I display a Loading dialog. For this I use Acr.XamForms.UserDiaologs library.

The code that I use is like below:

```
string Url = String.Format(category_url);
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();

using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Duke u ngarkuar..."))
contents = await hc.GetStringAsync(Url);
```

It works fine when I used in the inner pages of the app, but when I use in the first page it throws me the following error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: What does the stack trace show?  Is the null value coming from within UserDialogs, or from your code?

Answer (score 0):

It must be something with a null reference value, have a look on the debugger to `category_url`, `UserDialogs` and double check if `hc` is being created correctly, step by step on your debugger.